# How to get the absolute path location for this OutputStream?

Tags: java

```
byte bWrite [] = {11,21,3,40,5};
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
System.out.println("Created successfully"+os.getAbsolutePath());
```

This is my code.I have to get the location for "test.txt".please check it out if it is some other way to implement...?

Answer (score 9):

`FileOUtputStream` also has  `File` constructor so you can use that.

```
File out = new File("test.txt");

OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(out);
System.out.println("Created successfully "+out.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 5):

Getting this information *after* you've only got an `OutputStream` variable feels like the wrong approach to me. After all, there's no guarantee that an `OutputStream` is writing to a file at all - it could be a `ByteArrayOutputStream` or writing to a socket. You can get this information before you create the `FileOutputStream` though. For example:

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
System.out.println("Absolute path: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Or

```
Path path = Paths.get("text.txt");
System.out.println("Absolute path: " + path.toAbsolutePath());
```

... then create the `FileOutputStream` based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put your desired absolute path as the parameter of the constructor of FileOutputStream?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried your code with FileOutputStream it didn't work at all. But I was successful with the following code.

```
OutputStream os = openFileOutput("test.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
System.out.println("Created successfully" + getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/test.txt");
```

getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() appears to get the absolute path to the default location for openFileOutput.